Adding Groped Products items to the cart using the Api
I am using this endpoint :
http://mage.local/rest/V1/carts/3747/items

and this is the body:
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "8717752030514",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "3747"
  }
}

I have checked the above associated product have the in stock, also have quantity.
But when I do this I am getting this :
Product you are trying to add is not available

My parent sku is demo_8717752030514.
All things are available in the Magento instance.
I want to place the order for the grouped products.

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/tutorials/orders/order-add-items/

I have tried this but same answer

Hello @rana, You are using the wrong payload. I have given you the correct payload; try this. As you are providing only parent SKUs and not including child items, I have corrected the request for adding group products to the cart.

Try this solution here is the sample request. map data according to your request :
End Point For logged customer: rest/V1/carts/mine/items
End point for guest customer : POST <base_url>/rest/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items
Request Body
For adding a grouped product, the request body needs to specify each associated product along with its qty. Here's a sample payload:
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "grouped-product-sku",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "customer_cart_id",
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "custom_options": [],
        "bundle_options": [],
        "configurable_item_options": [],
        "grouped_items": [
          {
            "sku": "associated-simple-product1-sku",
            "qty": 2
          },
          {
            "sku": "associated-simple-product2-sku",
            "qty": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

Example cURL Command for Guest User
curl -X POST "<base_url>/rest/V1/guest-carts/<cart_id>/items" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "grouped-product-sku",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "guest_cart_id",
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "grouped_items": [
          {
            "sku": "associated-simple-product1-sku",
            "qty": 2
          },
          {
            "sku": "associated-simple-product2-sku",
            "qty": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}'


but in the above your Api you are also adding the quantity for the parent , but for the grouped the quantity will be only associated products

You have to give the parent qty. Did you try the sample request as per your need? let me know after trying this request you are getting any issues.
